# C# NPOI how to get Cell address ("A1", "CY100",...) from cell value

Tags: c#, interop, npoi

I'm using  NPOI to make a report (With dynamic cols) and have an issue that NPOI cannot attach file as Object to excel, so I use the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to do that, the problem is Interop need the cell address (As "CY100") while NPOI use cell value, so How I can get the Cell address as string from cell value?
I see that the NPOI CellRangeAddress can solve but it quite bad, like:

```
string valueIWant = new CellRangeAddress(1, 1, 1, 1).FormatAsString().Split(':')[0];
```

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

To translate between row and column indexes and string addresses in NPOI you can use the `CellAddress` class.

```
string address = new CellAddress(2, 1).FormatAsString();  // B3
```

To go the other way:

```
var cellAddr = new CellAddress("CY100");
var row = cellAddr.Row;      // 99
var col = cellAddr.Column;   // 102
```